# Show Pager row, but hide page numbers in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview, pager

Simple problem.

I have an ASP.net GridView (VS2005) and it has page numbers, but when there is less than the maximum rows per page (< 10), the Pager row disappears. This makes my gridview look ugly, like as if there's a missing row at the bottom.

I can force display the Pager row, but I need to hide the page number 1, because it's obvious we're on PAGE ONE !

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gvFTUNSENT" runat="server" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="gvCSS" Width="100%"
                    DataKeyNames="StudentID,StudentUnitID" DataSourceID="sdsFTUNSENT" 
                    GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                    OnPreRender="GridView_PreRender" 
                    OnLoad="GridView_Load" 
                    OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" >
                    <RowStyle Wrap="True" Height="48px" />
                    <Columns>
...blahblah
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="cssPager" BackColor="#6B696B" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" Height="100%" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNDF1" runat="server" Text="NO DATA FOUND" Font-Size="X-Large" Width="500px" style="text-align:center" />
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Here I force show the Pager row...

```
protected void GridView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

    //keep showing pager line even if there is only one row of data
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)gv.BottomPagerRow;
    if (gvr != null)
        gvr.Visible = true;
}
```

But I don't want to see Page 1 in there, so I tried this ...

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
{
    //keep showing pager line even if there is only one row of data
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)e.Row;
    if (gvr != null)
    {
        gvr.Visible = true;

        //...but hide page number if there is only one page
        if (gv.PageCount == 1)
        {
            gv.ShowFooter = true;
            gv.PagerSettings.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But it actually hides the entire Pager row! No! I want to hide only the page numbers.

The ShowFooter, is so it looks like the gridview is a box, closed off. But it's still ugly. I'd rather not use it if I can just keep the Pager row showing and being able to hide anything in it. ie.. keep background color intact.

Any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager && GridView1.PageCount==1 )
    { e.Row.Style.Add("color", "white"); }
 }
```

Or, if you don't want to deal with colors you can try this (but I think it's less robust)

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager && GridView1.PageCount==1 )
    {
        var a = e.Row.Controls;
        if (a.Count>0 && a[0] is TableCell)
        {
            var b = a[0].Controls[0].Controls[0] as TableRow;
            if (b != null)
            {
                //This is actually your page 1 text
                b.Cells[0].Text = "";
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The last version worked, but because there is nothing there now, the Pager row's height shrinks because when there are numbers, the compiler expands it slightly to make room for the page numbers. I've tried Height property but it's not quite right.

Comment: Actually I went with your 2nd answer, but instead of removing the text entirely, I've changed the color code to match the background. Works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

e.Row.Controls.Clear();

insted

e.Row.Style.Add("color", "white");

its work better..

Comment: That's what I did as per my response to the answer below.

Comment: yes, but its always better to clear controls from row to implement purpose of hiding it.